# Python: Use multiprocessing to create paramiko ssh clients

Tags: python, ssh, amazon-ec2, paramiko

I am working on a project which requires me to run about 500-1000 machines over the cloud(like Amazon EC2 instances). I need to SSH into these machines and execute certain commands and collect the log files.

Doing this sequentially is very slow over 500 to 1000 machines and I want to try doing it using the `multiprocessing` module to distribute the task of creating `paramiko.SSHClient()` objects to multiple processes so that the initial SSH clients setup speeds up.

However, on using the `multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async()` to create SSH clients concurrently the program errors out with an exception

```
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<paramiko.client.SSHClient object at 0x7ff450625490>'. Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed",)'
```

**Sample Code**

```
import multiprocessing
import paramiko

def create_one_client(ip_address, key_file):
    # creates and returns an paramik.SSHClient() object

def create_multiple_clients():

    ip_list = ["1.2.3.4", "5.6.7.8.9"]
    key_file = "key.pem"

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
    results = list()
    ssh_clients = list()

    for i in range(len(ip_list)):
        result = pool.apply_async(create_one_client, (ip_address, key_file))
        results.append(result)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    for result in results:
        ssh_clients.append(result.get())
```

This creates a few instances and then crashes. Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure your problem is CPU bound? If not, try `threading`. All I/O operations release the GIL, so you will get parallelism.

Comment: You'll need to show us what the code is for creating your `SSHClient` objects. You're running into a pickling error: `create_one_client` is trying to serialize its results but `thread` objects cannot be serialized.